# PowerBI: Calculated Table containing values in one but not other

Tags: powerbi

Brand new to PowerBI. I have two tables, both containing IP addresses.

Table 1:

```
column: hostname
1.2.3.4
2.3.4.5
3.4.5.6
```

Table 2:

```
column: ipaddress
2.3.4.5
3.4.5.6
```

Both tables are pulled dynamically.

I want a third table dynamically calculated as:

```
IP addresses that are in table1 but NOT in table2
```

In the above example, table3 would be:

```
column: ip
1.2.3.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question can be solved by `merge queries` easily, accept the answer if helping :)

Merge Queries > Merge Queries as new:

[image]

Choose both table > select`Left Anti`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use DAX expression. Go to Data pane -> New Table
https://dax.guide/except/

Table3 = EXCEPT ( Table1, Table2 )

[image]